# MongoDB Acceso Remoto

Tags: base-de-datos, mongodb, centos

Me he instalado un `MongoDB` en `OpenSUSE` versión 42.3. La versión de `MongoDB` es:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.10
```

En el archivo de:

```
/etc/mongodb.conf
```

Tengo esta configuracióin:

```
# What type of connections to allow.
net:
port: 27017
bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

Lo cual debería permitirme conectarme remotamente.

Bien desde un `Windows` y un `CentOS 7` intento conectarme remotamente y me indica error.
Las máquinas hacen ping entre ellas y tienen en la `DNS` la `IP` del `OpenSUSE`.

Intento remoto desde `CentOS 7`:

```
mongo --host 192.168.0.173
MongoDB shell version v3.4.13
connecting to: mongodb://192.168.0.173:27017/
2018-02-18T16:55:48.921+0100 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to    192.168.0.173:27017, in(connect), reason: Network is unreachable
2018-02-18T16:55:48.923+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 192.168.0.173:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:240:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Comment: Habilitaste el puerto 27017 de tu router?
Usas tu ip privada o publica?
te creaste un usuario para validar la conexion?
Agreganos mas info amigo.

Comment: según la versión de mongo bindear a 0.0.0.0 puede o no resultar, lo mas seguro es que le pongas 127.0.0.1 y la ip del adaptador. asimismo según la versión de mongo esa lista va con comas, comas sin espacios, entre corchetes y un par de variantes extra segun el formato del .conf